# Why does the *Moderator ♦* in area 51 not link to A theory of moderation?

Tags: discussion, bug, area-51

Take a look at [Tim post ♦ profile on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/202/tim-post). The **Moderator ♦** beside the gravatar

[image]

doesn't link to [A theory of moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). unlike [his meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tiny-tim) and other profiles.

Was the link purposely removed on area51 or is this a bug (or maybe it never existed)?.

Comment: Technically it's probably not *as* applicable seeing as all Area 51 moderators are Stack Exchange employees, not elected volunteers...but there's some useful content in there regardless. The "why" is an easy one though; Area 51 is a different code base, so it doesn't automatically get changes applied to the normal Q&A sites, and I guess no one noticed/worried about it until you brought it up. :)

Comment: hmmmm. Drive-by downvotes on Meta SO will never stop